# Custom TypeFace in Kotlin Programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-typeface

How to set typeface of any `TextView`. Using java we do something like this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

How such operation could be performed while using kotlin. Which will be the efficient way to do this in kotlin? Is there any better way provided with kotlin?

```
holder.itemView.title.typeface = ?
```

Comment: Won't `holder.itemView.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)` work?

Comment: yes i know this way, but i want to know how to achieve this in kotlin language support

Comment: From [the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html): _"single-argument methods with names starting with `set` are represented as properties in Kotlin"_ `setTypeface` is not a single-argument method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks after lot of research i solved it in single line

```
holder.itemView.title.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
```

Hope it helps someone else !!

Answer (score 4):

```
  val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(applicationContext.assets, "font/roboto.ttf")
        speedometerAdvance.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Please provide some description of your solution to the problem.

Comment: i did this in Kotline. if you want to change textview font style then you can use these line of code in kotline
 for Java i will post Java code as well

Answer (score 2):

Another option may be an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions).

```
fun TextView.type(style : Int) {
    setTypeface(null, style)
}

// usage
textView.type(BOLD)
```

Comment: nice one ,sweeter , slimmer ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Answer**

*If you want to use your custom typeface, **Typeface.createFromAsset()** helps for the job!*

*This example to use in Fragment. In Activity, you do not need to write "activity!!".*

```
yourTextview.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity!!.assets, "fonts/Forza-Bold.otf")
```

If you want use default typefaces:

```
yourTextview.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
val tv = findViewById(R.id.custom) as TextView
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I can understand that you want to do the **same thing** you have asked but **in Kotlin,** 
the **kotlin equivalent will be** :

```
    holder.itemView.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD) ,
```

Because this **method with two parameters** and **not a setter** so you can  not assign a value directly like property of data class. If you do then you are **not doing the same thing.**

**Your answer** is **similar** to **this in java**

```
    holder.itemView.title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Comment: thanks for the valuable response, but i have never noticed this method before

Comment: you are welcome bro :) did I solve your issue or added more ? hahha

Comment: you did solved my issue bro :) but i did found more efficient single line way

Comment: That's awesome bro, now you can edit  your question or answer so that they point at same thing or accept relevant answers :)